# Loading and writing CSV file in QTableView with Python 3.10 for QGIS Plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, csv, qt-designer

I know there are a lot of similar questions... but I can't implement them.

How can I load a CSV file and write that into a QTableView?

My first step was to browse it.

```
    def select_input_file(self):
    filename, _filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self.dlg, "Select input file ","", 
        ("GeoPackages (*.gpkg);;Comma separated values (*.csv);;Shapefiles (*.shp)")
        )
    self.dlg.Input_Box.setText(filename)
```

In the next step, I want to load it and write it in the QTableView called table.

```
    def show(self):
    self.table = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
    filename = self.dlg.Input_Box.text()
    with open(filename, "r") as fileInput:
        for row in csv.reader(fileInput):    
            items = [
                QtGui.QStandardItem(field)
                for field in row
            ]
            self.table.appendRow(items)
```

But I get this error:

```
              self.table = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self)
         TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
          QStandardItemModel(parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'GTool'
          QStandardItemModel(int, int, parent: QObject = None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'GTool'
```

These packages are loaded:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QCoreApplication
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import QIcon
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QAction, QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem, QFileDialog, QDialog, QPushButton, QDialogButtonBox, QLineEdit
from qgis.core import QgsProject, Qgis
from qgis.utils import iface
```

Comment: We come to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. If the title has an "and" you're likely to get *unfocused* closure votes. Please [Edit] the Question to isolate the task at issue.

Comment: This is really a programming question, not a GIS question, so it probably be somewhere else, like stackoverflow. That said, your problem is that you are trying to create your table as a QStandardItemModel, when you said you were going to use QTableView

Comment: If there are a lot of similar questions please provide links to at least some of them within the body of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the file [https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/csv/airtravel.csv), you can use the following

```py
import csv

filename, _filter = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
    iface.mainWindow(), "Select input file ","", 
    ("Comma separated values (*.csv);;GeoPackages (*.gpkg);;Shapefiles (*.shp)")
)

model = QStandardItemModel()
tableView = QTableView()

tableView.setModel(model)
tableView.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

with open(filename, "r") as fileInput:
    for i, row in enumerate(csv.reader(fileInput)):
        if i == 0:
            model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([r.strip().strip('"') for r in row])
        else:
            items = [
                QStandardItem(field.strip())
                for field in row
            ]
            model.appendRow(items)

tableView.show()
```